# How To Raise An Event On A Web User Control In VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, web, controls

I have a .NET 4.0 Web Application project written in VB.  I have a Master Page from which all subsequent webpages are derived.  Each webpage comprises of one or more Web User Controls.  One particular WUC comprises of a Panel that the user can click on - it acts and feels like a button - taking them to another page of relevant data.

I now need to capture the OnClick event of the panel and carry out a task before redirecting the user to another page.  The solution I have tried so far includes:

(1) Insert the following code after the Partial Class... opening statements on the WUC:

```
Public Event Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Protected Overridable Sub OnClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    RaiseEvent Click(Me, e)
End Sub
```

(2) Include the following subroutine within the WUC:

```
Public Sub common_button1_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
  ' Do Stuff here
End Sub
```

(3) Have the following statement within the Page_Prerender subroutine of the WUC:

```
AddHandler Me.Click, AddressOf common_button1_Click1
```

How do I now use this event handler, so that when I click on the WUC it fires?  I was thinking that the reference to the WUC on my webpage would have the attribute 'OnClick' within it and point to 'common_button1_Click', but the option does not appear to be within the IntelliSense of Visual Studio.  Example ...

Many thanks in anticipation of your responses.

Answer (score 0):

In our implementation, we put the AddHandler code in Page_Load instead of PreRender. This is also added on every single load whether it's a postback or not.